# What is the difference between __metaclass__ attribute and metaclass kwarg

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the difference between the class attribute `__metaclass__` and the class keyword argument `metaclass`.

Consider this example:

```
class Meta1(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs.update({'x': 100})
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)


class Foo(metaclass=Meta1):
    pass


class Bar(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta1



f = Foo()
b = Bar()

f.x
>> 100
b.x
>> AttributeError: 'Bar' object has no attribute 'x'
```

I had thought `Foo` and `Bar` instances would be functionally equivalent, but clearly they are not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__metaclass__` attribute is python2 syntax for declaring a metaclass. The `metaclass=` kwarg is python3 syntax for it.

If you need one codebase to support both python2 and python3 you can use `future`, which has [a helper for this](https://python-future.org/what_else.html#metaclasses).

Comment: Ah, I see -- thanks for quickly clearing that up. I should of figured that ><

Comment: What does `__future__` offer in terms of metaclass compatibility? I'm only aware of [`six.with_metaclass`](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.with_metaclass).

Comment: @a_guest  This is referring to 3rd-party [python-future](https://python-future.org), not stdlib `__future__`.